# Ctrl + Up/Down to scroll through Terminal.app window

Tags: terminal

In the Ubuntu terminal, `Shift + PgUp/PgDn` scrolls the window up or down a page, and `Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down` scrolls the window up or down a line. On my Mac, `Shift + PgUp/PgDn` works the same as on Ubuntu, but `Ctrl + Up/Down` triggers Expose instead. Is there a key combination that I can use in the Mac Terminal.app to scroll up or down a single line at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "View" menu.

<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> scroll the window a single line.

Comment: Thanks. That does work, however, the View menu actually indicates that the key combo is `Option + Command + Up Arrow`. But that doesn't actually work because it's superseded by the Jump to Previous Bookmark shortcut. Can you explain why Page Up and Page Down work in place of the up and down arrow keys?